# How to use Amazon EFS with Amazon Lightsail

Tags: amazon-web-services

I'm trying to follow [How to use EFS with Amazon Lightsail | Scratchpad](https://scratchpad.blog/howto/how-to-use-efs-with-aws-lightsail/) to mount a EFS into one of my Lightsail instance.

*BTW, I do not have any EFS setup at the moment.*

I'm a bit stuck at step 1 here so I did:

```
aws lightsail peer-vpc


aws lightsail is-vpc-peered
```

Response from AWS CLI contains:

```
{
    "operation": {
        "status": "Succeeded",
    }
}
```

The next step is with the  *CloudFormation template*
which I am not sure where to input that nor how to use it for that step.

My ultimate goal is for my Ubuntu server (**REGION:** ap-southeast-1) on Lightsail to have a mounted EFS.

Comment: I followed the same blog post to mount EFS on a Lightsail instant. No problem as of Dec 9th, 2019

Answer (score -4):

yeah good luck - this guy's blog post is a hot mess, it's completely useless.

How about someone provide REGULAR INSTRUCTIONS for MANUAL setup through the Amazon Web Console.

He doesn't even explain how  (or where) to figure out how to use the AWS CLI to accomplish what he's talking about as he switching between 2 of the most complicated methods imaginable - i'd NEVER hire that guy to do anything for me that's for damn sure.